# I can't connect HTTPS on Ubuntu Apache2 SSL port 443 (https://PUBLIC_IP/)

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl

Good Afternoon Folks,

So, I wanted my web applications a little more secure on my Ubuntu 16.04 server. Im running Plex, Torrent client, some other crap and an Apache2 server.
I wanted to make the connection HTTPS so I used [this](https://www.vultr.com/docs/configure-apache-with-select-signed-tls-ssl-certificate-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial to help me install the certificate.

My Problem: I CANNOT connect to my webserver over HTTPS public IP. (ex:https://PUBLIC_IP/)

I have set a redirect in 000-default.conf to always use HTTPS, but I checked without the redirect and I *could* access (http://PUBLIC_IP/), which is logical because it runs over port 80.

But HTTPS runs over port 443, it is NOT blocked by firewall as far as I know,

- UFW is good to go
- I added it to iptables as well.

Port 80 and 443 are both opened on my router.
But when I check on "https://canyouseeme.org/" I can only see 80 and I can't see 443

I ran the "lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -P" command and 443 IS listed.

---

```
$ sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -P
```

apache2   3632                root    4u  IPv6  34173      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)

apache2   3632                root    6u  IPv6  34177      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)

apache2   3635            www-data    4u  IPv6  34173      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)

apache2   3635            www-data    6u  IPv6  34177      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)

apache2   3636            www-data    4u  IPv6  34173      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)

apache2   3636            www-data    6u  IPv6  34177      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)

---

I have tried changing/adding Listen 443 to ports.conf.

I CAN telnet localhost 443.

I CAN'T telnet PUBLIC_IP 443.

I have double checked a lot of things and I didn't make any mistakes.

Also tried some other things but as far as I can see there shouldn't be a problem at all.

Feel free to ask for logs and files.

Now I am not the type to ask a question quickly, I couldn't find anybody with the same problem on the internet.

In other words "help".

If you think the title sucks, let me know a better one. I find this problem hard to describe.

Grtz Mextro

---

**UPDATE**
**DEFAULT-SSL.CONF**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>

        ServerAdmin [MY_EMAIL]
        ServerName [PUBLIC_IP]

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        #   SSL Engine Switch:
        #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
        SSLEngine on

        #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
        #   the ssl-cert package. See
        #   /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz for more info.
        #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
        #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

        #   Server Certificate Chain:
        #   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
        #   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
        #   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
        #   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
        #   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
        #   certificate for convinience.
        #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/server-ca.crt

        #   Certificate Authority (CA):
        #   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
        #   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
        #   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
        #   Note: Inside SSLCACertificatePath you need hash symlinks
        #        to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
        #        Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
        #SSLCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/certs/
        #SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt

        #   Certificate Revocation Lists (CRL):
        #   Set the CA revocation path where to find CA CRLs for client
        #   authentication or alternatively one huge file containing all
        #   of them (file must be PEM encoded)
        #   Note: Inside SSLCARevocationPath you need hash symlinks
        #        to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
        #        Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
        #SSLCARevocationPath /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/
        #SSLCARevocationFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/ca-bundle.crl

        #   Client Authentication (Type):
        #   Client certificate verification type and depth.  Types are
        #   none, optional, require and optional_no_ca.  Depth is a
        #   number which specifies how deeply to verify the certificate
        #   issuer chain before deciding the certificate is not valid.
        #SSLVerifyClient require
        #SSLVerifyDepth  10

        #   SSL Engine Options:
        #   Set various options for the SSL engine.
        #   o FakeBasicAuth:
        #    Translate the client X.509 into a Basic Authorisation.  This means that
        #    the standard Auth/DBMAuth methods can be used for access control.  The
        #    user name is the `one line' version of the client's X.509 certificate.
        #    Note that no password is obtained from the user. Every entry in the user
        #    file needs this password: `xxj31ZMTZzkVA'.
        #   o ExportCertData:
        #    This exports two additional environment variables: SSL_CLIENT_CERT and
        #    SSL_SERVER_CERT. These contain the PEM-encoded certificates of the
        #    server (always existing) and the client (only existing when client
        #    authentication is used). This can be used to import the certificates
        #    into CGI scripts.
        #   o StdEnvVars:
        #    This exports the standard SSL/TLS related `SSL_*' environment variables.
        #    Per default this exportation is switched off for performance reasons,
        #    because the extraction step is an expensive operation and is usually
        #    useless for serving static content. So one usually enables the
        #    exportation for CGI and SSI requests only.
        #   o OptRenegotiate:
        #    This enables optimized SSL connection renegotiation handling when SSL
        #    directives are used in per-directory context.
        #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

        #   SSL Protocol Adjustments:
        #   The safe and default but still SSL/TLS standard compliant shutdown
        #   approach is that mod_ssl sends the close notify alert but doesn't wait for
        #   the close notify alert from client. When you need a different shutdown
        #   approach you can use one of the following variables:
        #   o ssl-unclean-shutdown:
        #    This forces an unclean shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. no
        #    SSL close notify alert is send or allowed to received.  This violates
        #    the SSL/TLS standard but is needed for some brain-dead browsers. Use
        #    this when you receive I/O errors because of the standard approach where
        #    mod_ssl sends the close notify alert.
        #   o ssl-accurate-shutdown:
        #    This forces an accurate shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. a
        #    SSL close notify alert is send and mod_ssl waits for the close notify
        #    alert of the client. This is 100% SSL/TLS standard compliant, but in
        #    practice often causes hanging connections with brain-dead browsers. Use
        #    this only for browsers where you know that their SSL implementation
        #    works correctly.
        #   Notice: Most problems of broken clients are also related to the HTTP
        #   keep-alive facility, so you usually additionally want to disable
        #   keep-alive for those clients, too. Use variable "nokeepalive" for this.
        #   Similarly, one has to force some clients to use HTTP/1.0 to workaround
        #   their broken HTTP/1.1 implementation. Use variables "downgrade-1.0" and
        #   "force-response-1.0" for this.
        # BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
        #       nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        #       downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

---

**UPDATE**
**PORTS.CONF**

```
  # If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
    # have to change the VirtualHost statement in
    # /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

    Listen 80

    <IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
    </IfModule>

    # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

---

**UPDATE ERROR LOG**
The error log located at /var/log/apache2/error.log.1

```
[Tue Jan 29 16:17:12.978482 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 3632:tid 3074254592] AH01906: [PUBLIC_IP]:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Tue Jan 29 16:17:12.979061 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 3632:tid 3074254592] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jan 29 16:17:12.979087 2019] [core:notice] [pid 3632:tid 3074254592] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Jan 30 06:25:13.336166 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 3632:tid 3074254592] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this messag
```

Comment: please show your virtual host config

Comment: There you go blurred out ip and email

Comment: and config for port 80? Which works as you say.

Comment: And this is the ports.conf, i tried adding/changing 80 to 443 with no result

Comment: did you do `a2enmod` and `a2ensite` like in the tutorial? Which config did you `a2ensite` for http (port 80) to work? Was it the same file as for https (port 443)? Did you check apache log files?

Comment: Here you have the error file.
Yes I did the a2enmod command as in the tutorial.
As for the  _"Which config did you a2ensite for http (port 80) to work? Was it the same file as for https (port 443)?"_ I am not sure what you mean by this.

Comment: google on the log line _Could not reliably determine..._.

Comment: Okay so I Google searched and solved the specific error, it's not in the list with errors anymore. But it's still not working.

Comment: I don't know. But...when I look again at the info you provided here...`lsof` lists IPv6 only? Maybe you need specify a full ip address for `Listen` command? And then one more thing - what is `PUBLIC_IP` in your text? Numbers (ipv4) or text?

Comment: I noticed the IPv6 too, dont know about it. PUBLIC_IP is the replacement for my public ip, privacy reasons. My server is insecure atm so I can't share my public ip. They are numbers ofcourse it's a home server, no domain name involved.

Comment: that is, you want ssl to ip address? Do you have a certificate for ip address? If not, it will not work. But it should throw some statement about it, shouldn't it? What is actually shown on the browser window (or whatever way you test it) when you try https that ip?

Comment: It just doesnt load at all, ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. It loads on http ofcourse. I entered my ip during the certificate registration. Im also willing to bind a domain name to my server, but I haven't yet figured out how I should do this. Should I just register the ip adress of my server at my domain name provider ? If that fixes the problem I am willing to try that.

Comment: Normally you get a certificate for a domain name. In config it **is** ServerName.

Comment: So you suggest I retry generating the certificate with servername instead of public ip?